# Does it cost more memory to load classes with more methods?

Tags: c#

Essentially, will more memory be used by instances of Foo when its value is acquired like this:

```
public class Foo
{

    internal double bar;

    double GetBar(){ return bar; }

}
```

or like this?

```
public class Foo
{

    internal double bar;

}  

public static class FooManager
{
    public static double GetBar(Foo foo) { return foo.bar; }
}
```

That is, is memory used per-method per-object or per-type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instances themselves only have a single pointer to a table of methods that is loaded with the class, so there isn't extra per-instance overhead for having more methods, only fields.

The second example will use slightly more memory in total because you have definitions for two classes and so more per-class overhead (and as originally written, with FooManager as a non-static class, you need a FooManager instance), but the amount of memory used by each Foo instance is the same.

Comment: Thanks! I was just curious :P

Comment: @Random I presume that point is going same for all the languages. Atleast for C++.

Comment: @prabhakaran Well, in C++, a class without virtual methods doesn't even have that one pointer.

Comment: You should explicitly answer the question, the second example will naturally consume more memory.

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound Technically the question was phrased to refer to the size of the Foo instance only. Edited.

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound That is not part of the instance. Instance is 24 bytes (object header and one double) either way.

Comment: Indeed, but it is more complete now. +1